# How to convert a 3 column csv file into a table (or matrix)

Tags: linux, command-line, csv, text-formatting, file-format

I have an CSV input file format like this, with a nucleotide sequence in field 1, text in field 2, and an integer in field 4:

```
ATGC,CD3,56
ATGC,CD4,67
ATGC,IgD,126
ATGC,IgM,127
AGTC,CD3,67
AGTC,CD4,78
AGTC,IgD,102
AGTC,IgM,89
TCGA,CD3,334
TCGA,CD4,123
TCGA,IgD,456
TCGA,IgM,80
CGTA,CD3,54
CGTA,CD4,32
CGTA,IgD,82
CGTA,IgM,117
```

I opened this CSV file using Numbers in Mac it's display as 3 columns format, however, I want to convert it to the table(or Matrix) format (also a CSV file), making the first column, the nucleotide sequences, into a header, and want the result to also look like a table (or Matrix):

```
     ATGC  AGTC  TCGA  CGTA
CD3  56    67    334   54
CD4  67    78    123   32
IgD  126   102   456   82
IgM  127   89    80    117
```

Below is a section from my real input CSV file (sample `input.txt`):

```
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,-,,38
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,AnnexinV,,51
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD127,,39
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD138,,3
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD14,,2
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD16,,4
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD19,,10
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD20,,6
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD24,,21
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD25,,4
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD27,,87
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD3,,235
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD34,,5
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD38,,18
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD4,,412
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD43,,99
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD5,,430
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD56,,3
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,CD8,,7
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,IgD,,4
AGAATAGTCTGATTCT,IgM,,2
TGTGGTAGTTCGTCTC,-,,9
TGTGGTAGTTCGTCTC,AnnexinV,,42
TGTGGTAGTTCGTCTC,CD127,,6
TGTGGTAGTTCGTCTC,CD138,,4
TGTGGTAGTTCGTCTC,CD16,,40
TGTGGTAGTTCGTCTC,CD19,,7
TGTGGTAGTTCGTCTC,CD20,,2
TGTGGTAGTTCGTCTC,CD24,,24
TGTGGTAGTTCGTCTC,CD25,,2
```

How can I do this using Linux text formatting commands?

Comment: Where are the numbers in columns 2 and higher coming from? Your examples are too small; there's no AGAATAGTCTGATTCT allele example for CD3 in the first sample, for example, for us to extrapolate from. It's also customary here to provide text, not a screenshot, as  you've got the text, and asking us to retype it to test with is counterproductive.

Comment: Also, please do not post pictures of text; instead please just post text.

Comment: Provide sample text samples

Comment: @K7AAY I edited the answer, hope it's much clear now.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I changed it to text

Comment: @DudiBoy I edited the answer, hope it's more clear now

Comment: Exactly what we need! Column A has 4 values; ATGC  AGTC  TCGA  and CGTA which you want to become the header of Row 1. Column B becomes Column A of the new matrix, and the integer values of Column C fill in the (4x4) grid of the matrix.

Comment: What is your purpose in doing this? It's facile in R, using `reshape`, for example.

Comment: Have you tried the answers below? If there is one that is good for you, mark it, it is useful for this space. If there isn't any, add comments and let us know what problems you have

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```c
{
    ks[$1 $2] = $3; # save the third column using the first and second as index
    k1[$1]++;       # save the first column
    k2[$2]++;       # save the second column
}
END {                                # After processing input
    for (j in k1) {                  # loop over the first column 
        printf "\t%s", j;            # and print column headers
    };
    print "";                        # newline
    for (i in k2) {                  # loop over the second 
        printf "%s", i;              # print it as row header
        for (j in k1) {              # loop over first again
            printf "\t%s", ks[j i];  # and print values
        }
        print "";                    # newline
    }
}
```

Output:

```
~ awk -F, -f foo.awk foo
        AGTC    ATGC    CGTA    TCGA
CD4     78      67      32      123
IgD     102     126     82      456
IgM     89      127     117     80
CD3     67      56      54      334
```

Comment: I tried your code but it just convert the first and the second columns, the third column was not filling the matrix(the matrix is empty). I added a section of my real input file to the answer, please take a look.

Comment: Your real data has 4 columns, and the third is empty. Try with `$4` instead of `$3`.

Comment: I used your code and it did convert the format I want, but it seems like it didn't convert all the data , some of the data are missing

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) with

```
mlr --n2p --ifs "," label key,property,emptyfield,value \
then reshape -s key,value \
then unsparsify \
then cut -x -f emptyfield input.csv
```

You will have

```
property AGAATAGTCTGATTCT TGTGGTAGTTCGTCTC
-        38               9
AnnexinV 51               42
CD127    39               6
CD138    3                4
CD14     2                -
CD16     4                40
CD19     10               7
CD20     6                2
CD24     21               24
CD25     4                2
CD27     87               -
CD3      235              -
CD34     5                -
CD38     18               -
CD4      412              -
CD43     99               -
CD5      430              -
CD56     3                -
CD8      7                -
IgD      4                -
IgM      2                -
```

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` script solving your task:

script.awk

```
{
        arr[$1,$2] = $4; # read array values
        c1[$1] = 1;      # read row headers
        c2[$2] = 1;      # read row indexes
}
END {                # start fancy printing
        printf ("%-18s","");     # first line empty tab
        for (i1 in c1) printf("%-18s",i1); printf "\n";  # print headers
                     # print rows
        for (i2 in c2) {
                printf("%-18s",i2);  # print row index
                for (i1 in c1) {
                        printf("%-18d", arr[i1,i2]); # print row's values
                }
                printf "\n";          # terminat current row with newline
        }
}
```

runing:

```
awk -F "," -f script.awk input.txt
```

output:

```
                  TGTGGTAGTTCGTCTC  AGAATAGTCTGATTCT
CD4               0                 412
CD24              24                21
CD5               0                 430
CD43              0                 99
CD34              0                 5
CD25              2                 4
CD16              40                4
IgD               0                 4
CD27              0                 87
CD8               0                 7
CD19              7                 10
CD56              0                 3
CD38              0                 18
AnnexinV          42                51
-                 9                 38
CD127             6                 39
CD20              2                 6
CD138             4                 3
IgM               0                 2
CD3               0                 235
CD14              0                 2
```