# Converting rows to multiple columns

Tags: awk

I have a big text file with 1,505,496 rows in the following format -

```
PAN     rs1  G    G 
PAB     rs1  G    G 
PAC     rs1  G    G 
PAE     rs1  G    G 
PAT     rs1  G    G 
PAN     rs2  T    T 
PAB     rs2  T    T 
PAC     rs2  T    T 
PAE     rs2  T    T 
PAT     rs2  T    T 
PAN     rs3  A    C 
PAB     rs3  A    C 
PAC     rs3  A    C 
PAE     rs3  A    C 
PAT     rs3  A    C 
. 
.
```

and I want my desired output to look like this:

```
          Rs1   rs1       rs2   rs2       rs3   rs3      ....
PAN        G    G          T        T       A      C
PAB        G    G          T        T       A      C
PAC        G    G          T        T       A      C
PAE        G    G          T        T       A      C
PAT        G    G          T        T       A      C
```

There are 1153 'rs' numbers and each 'rs' has ref and alt value (first column if each rs ref and second column is alt).

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397).

Comment: @lili What have you tried so far? How many `rs*` are there? Does every entry has all rs* values?

Comment: i have 1153 rs numbers and each rs has ref and alt value ( first column if each rs ref and second column is alt )

Comment: This question is almost identical to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522046), and my comment also applies here:  what is your purpose in doing this? It's facile in R, using `reshape`, for example.

Comment: Since there appear to be only 4 variants on the row headers `PA[NBCEAT]` how many columns do you expect.....??

Comment: i want  this format for ped file

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for arrays of arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
!seen[$1]++ { rowIds[++numRows] = $1 }
!seen[$2]++ { colIds[++numCols] = $2 }
{ vals[$1][$2] = $3 OFS $4 }
END {
    printf "%s%s", "", OFS
    for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
        colId = colIds[colNr]
        printf "%s%s%s%s", colId, OFS, colId, (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        rowId = rowIds[rowNr]
        printf "%s%s", rowId, OFS
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            colId = colIds[colNr]
            printf "%s%s", vals[rowId][colId], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
        rs1     rs1     rs2     rs2     rs3     rs3
PAN     G       G       T       T       A       C
PAB     G       G       T       T       A       C
PAC     G       G       T       T       A       C
PAE     G       G       T       T       A       C
PAT     G       G       T       T       A       C
```

Comment: thanks Ed,it works only for first 1000 columns and after that is empty. i am waiting for your helpgul reply. after 1000 columns the rs numbers exist but  rows in columns is empty.

Comment: There is nothing in my script that cares about how many rows or columns your input has. It will behave no differently for 1000000 columns than it does for 10. So, it must be your input file that changes after the first 1000 columns.

Comment: thanks Ed,i check again my txt file.it has 1,505,496 rows and 1153 rs

Comment: Again - as far as the script goes, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

gawk (multi dimensional array feature used):

```
{
    if($2 ~ "rs[0-9]+")
    {
        idx = substr($2, 3)
        max_rs = idx > max_rs ? idx : max_rs
        a[$1][idx * 2 - 1] = $3
        a[$1][idx * 2] = $4
    }
}

END{

    # header
    printf "\t"
    for (i = 1; i <= max_rs; ++i) {
       printf "rs" i "\trs" i "\t"
    }
    printf "\n"

    # entries
    for (entry in a) {
        printf entry "\t"
        for (i = 1; i <= max_rs*2; ++i) {
            printf a[entry][i] "\t"
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

It works by store all `rs[index]` column in `a[key][index*2-1]` and `a[key][index*2]` and output them in the `END`, `max_rs` is used to store the max `rs` number.

Comment: i run this by bash script but it does`t work.how can i run this script?

Comment: something like `awk -f 'script.awk' data`

Comment: when i run  awk -f 'script.awk' data , i got error below

Comment: max_rs = idx max_rs 1138 (my number of rs) idx : max_rs (suntax error)

Comment: i insert 1138 instead of ?  in code, is that wrong?

Comment: You don't need to change max_rs, it's calculated in the script, just copy the code into a file and execute it.

Comment: Don't use `printf input_data`, use `printf "%s", input_data` instead. The former will fail if/when the input data contains printf formatting characters like `%s`. Use `print ""` instead of `printf "\n"` so it'll work no matter what the value of ORS.

Comment: i tried this but it does`t work and give me "killed " error